# Puppeteer get data from input

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

The goal is to have a simple html with a text input and when the user submits the input with the instagram username, the puppeteer will receive the url `('https://instagram.com/${username}')` but I’m days trying to pass that $ {username} from the frontend to the backend and I can’t.

**HTML**

```
<form name="" action="">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="submitName()">
</form>
<script src="./scripts/index.js"></script>
```

**index.js**

```
const ig = require('./instagram');
async function submitName(){
  const inputUsername = document.querySelector('#username');
  const username = await inputUsername.value
  await ig.inicialize(`https://instagram.com/${username}`)
  console.log(`https://instagram.com/${username}`);
};
```

**instagram.js**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

    const instagram = {
        browser: null,
        page: null,
    
        inicialize: async (url) => {
            instagram.browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
            instagram.page = await instagram.browser.newPage();
            await instagram.page.goto(url)
    }
}
        
module.exports = instagram;
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I know I have to run the instagram.js node, but there's no way to run it without having the url, I'm already lost ...

Comment: You need a server (express) with an endpoint that is the form action.

Comment: Why using puppeteer and not a regular backend for form posting?